# how to check is user is log in in different view controllers in firebase

Tags: ios, swift

I am making an app where user can upload files on cloud and retrieve later, but I am stuck.

My question is how to check if user is logged in or not,
if login page should be my view controller and every time a user opens the app they have to login or is there some way we can skip this procedure?

I tried making home page an initial view controller and checking in view didload if there is any user or not using `auth.auth().currentuser.uid` but I don't feel good about using it please any help would be appreciated.

I am new to firebase

Answer (score 2):

```
if Auth.auth().currentuser.uid != nil {
   //success code 
}
```

in AppDelegate in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`

```
if Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid != nil { 
self.window?.rootViewController = UINavigationController.init(rootViewController: viewController1()) 
} else {
self.window?.rootViewController = UINavigationController.init(rootViewController: viewController2())
}
```

Comment: do I have to do this in every view controller

Comment: You can add that in root view controller ....if using programmatically to auto layout. add it in App delegate if using storyboard add it in the first view controller

Comment: ` if Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid {
            
            self.window?.rootViewController = UINavigationController.init(rootViewController: viewController())
        } `

Answer (score 0):

to check if user is logged in with firebase, you need to implement this in the didFinishLaunchingWithOptions in the appDelegate

```
if Auth.auth().currentUser != nil {
        // the user is logged in, you can now redirect to another view controller
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "YourStoryboardVCName") as! YourViewController
        self.window?.rootViewController = vc
    }
```

Comment: this is solving my problem, but my question is : is this the correct way?

Comment: Yes it is if you use it in the appDelegate ! :)

Comment: but then i am not able to pop to login page from navigation controller upon sign out

Comment: To correctly sign out from firebase you need to use try! Auth.auth().signOut()
            UserDefaults.standard.removeObject(forKey: "uid")
            UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
            if let storyboard = self.storyboard {
                //change view controller
            }

Answer (score 0):

I think the below code might help you.

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        configureFirebase()
        configureApplicationScreen() 
        return true
}

// To determine which screen will be displayed when application is launched
func configureApplicationScreen() {

        guard let rootNav = window?.rootViewController as? UINavigationController else {
            return
        }

         // Might need to change the code inside if let depending your requirement
        if let _ = Auth.auth().currentUser, UserDefaults.isUserLoggedIn {
            let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
            let sideMenuVC = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SideMenuController")
            rootNav.navigationBar.isHidden = true
            rootNav.addChild(sideMenuVC)
        }
    }

extension UserDefaults {

    static var isUserLoggedIn: Bool {
        get {
            return UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "IsUserLoggedIn")
        }
        set {
            UserDefaults.standard.set(newValue, forKey: "IsUserLoggedIn")
            UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
        }

    }

}
```

Once user is logged in you need to save the status in your UserDefault like
"UserDefaults.isUserLoggedIn = true" and you need to check it when the application is launched in the AppDelegate class as stated above.